# MISRA 2004: 10.1/R warning

Tags: misra

```
S32 pLeftX;
pLeftX = pos.x - 1; //Getting a Misra 2004: 10.1/R warning for this.
```

Here, `pos.x` is of type int.

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I bet the question is: "why?"...

Answer (score 1):

If `pos.x` is really `int` and `S32` is a signed int type, then your static analyser is broken.

Implicit type conversion to a wider type of the same signedness is allowed by rule 10.1. If `pos.x` is int, then the types in the expression is `int + int`. The result is an `int`, which is always signed. This is then implicitly converted to a 32-bit signed int, which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would first look at how the tool is configured. What is the size of int? According to the C90 standard the size of int is implementation defined and can be 16 bit or greater. Assuming that S32 is a 32 bit signed integer type, my understanding is that:

1. If the size of int is 32 bits then there is no problem.
2. If the size of int is greater that 32 bits then the problem is that there is an implicit conversion to a narrower type.
3. If the size of int is less that 32 bits then the problem is that the right hand side of the assignment is a complex expression and its result is implicitly converted to a wider type.